# Is there a way to access an overridden method within a multiple inheritance object in Python?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I have the following Python code. How do I get c to return 2 without changing the class definitions? Or differently stated. How to access overridden methods in an object with multiple inheritance?

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        return 1

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        return 2

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)

c = C()
c.foo() # Returns 1
```

Comment: Please post the result as an answer to your own question.

Comment: You will be able to add the answer to your own question after 8 hours.

Comment: Done, thanks for letting me know I should answer it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Just after asking this question I got an answer elsewhere so here goes:

```
import types
c.foo = types.MethodType(B.foo, c)
```

Comment: Just pointing out you're only changing object `c`, not the class.  `C().foo()` would still return 1.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the unbound method explicitly:

```
>> B.foo(c)
2
```